# Dual concept for p-primary component

Tags: group-theory

Is there a dual concept for the p-primary component of an abelian group?

EDIT:
I was thinking that if the p-primary component of an abelian group $G$ is the sum of all images of homomorphisms $f:\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\to G$, there is also a subgroup of $G$ that is the intersection of all kernels of homomorphisms $f:G\to \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$. This would be the dual of the p-primary component of $G$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Dual in what sense?

Comment: [Cross posted](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122687/dual-concept-for-the-p-primary-component) to MO without mentioning, question makes no sense, refuses to elaborate.  Voting to close